# Definite and indefinite articles with abstract nouns

Tags: articles

I have some difficulties in choosing between definite and indefinite articles with abstract nouns. I do know when we use a zero article with abstracts. But when we talk e.g. not about love in general, but about love of something we can use either the love of.. or a love of... What is the rule for choosing between "a" and "the" in this case?

P.S. Unfortunately, the explanation "we use (the) with specific nouns" would not work for me (and I don't reckon it would work for anyone else, since it is too vague)

Comment: "the" is always specific; "a" is never specific but I just do not have the energy for treatise writing this afternoon. It's too hot where I live and I hate air conditioning.

Comment: Here's a partial answer: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/231526/whats-the-difference-between-freedom-and-the-freedom-here/231544#231544

Comment: + A love of life can be a good thing. The love of life he showed was astonishing.